# Programmatically click the dropdown menu item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**CLick me here** button adds the pink block each time its being clicked.

Each pink block has the same menu with edit, delete and run

Everytime a new pink block is added by CLick me here button, it should make a auto click of edit menu of the respective added block so it opens the popup.

[image]

So it displays the fullscreen popup.

I have code so far as

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="clickme">Click me here</button>
  <script>
    $("#clickme").click(function (event) {
      $("body").append(`<ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />            

                <div class="btn-group float-end">
                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                        <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
    <div class="ms-5">A First item<br/>
    <small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
    <div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
        </ul>`)
    })

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are wanting to acheive in comparison to what is currently happening. Please give more and clearer details as to the process in order that we can understand your issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap own modal functions, specifically `.modal(show)` to achieve this, and an additional thing to note on this is that you are using same `id` on all modals which means your edit button will always open the very first modal that you append. to fix that I have added a `count` variable to make the `id`s dynamic.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="clickme">Click me here</button>
  <script>
    let count = 0;
    $("#clickme").click(function (event) {
      $("body").append(`<ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />            

            <div class="btn-group float-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle${count}" class="edit-btn" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
<div class="ms-5">A First item<br/>
<small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
<div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle${count}" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file ${count}</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>`)
      $(`#exampleModalToggle${count}`).modal("show");
      count++;
    })

  </script>

</body>
```